# No possibility to use two monitors with Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wayland

I use a TFT monitor on an ATI Radeon HD 7480D and a CRT display on an external USB graphic card. What with Ubuntu 17.04 works fine, isn't possible with Ubuntu 17.10. I only can use one monitor. If I connect the second one, I'm logged out and asked for my password.

Maybe the reason is Wayland ? Does anybody know a solution ?

Comment: 18.04 is off topic; all references removed.

Comment: Today's update solved my problem.
Good things come to those who wait :-)